I can't add users to contacts anymore in Telethon
I use teleton to send messages to customers of our pizzeria. First, I add the customer's number to my contacts. (because as far as I understand, I can only send messages to people who are in my contact list). And then I send the customer a message. It works. But after some time (a day or two), I can no longer add the user to my contacts. Is this a limitation imposed by telegram? Is there a way to avoid this?
I add a phone number to contacts using
contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id=client_id, phone=phone, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
result = await client(ImportContactsRequest([contact]))

Then I use this to send a message
await client.send_message(phone, msg)
But after a couple of days, all my attempts to add phones to contacts return with this phone in
retry_contacts=[]
I can still send messages to those who are already in my contacts, but I can no longer add any new contacts. This blocking did not go away after 4 days. I also tried to avoid this by adding not every client to my contacts, but only every third one. For this, I used a new number. But this number was also limited after a while. More time has passed, it seems like exactly three times more. But this does not solve the problem.
How can I make sure that this blocking does not appear and I can add contacts and send them messages?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
